# jquery multiple pop up with dimmer

Tags: jquery, css

I have code that works if you want one pop up with dimmer but I would like it to work with multiple on click popups. I'm not really sure on how to rework it to do multiple so some help would be appreciated. I've tried finding other pop up with dimmer jquerys but none of them seem to work for multiple.

```js
//This is the function that closes the pop-up
function endBlackout(){
    $(".blackout").css("display", "none");
    $(".msgbox").css("display", "none");
}

//This is the function that closes the pop-up
function strtBlackout(){
    $(".msgbox").css("display", "block");
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
}

//Sets the buttons to trigger the blackout on clicks
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(strtBlackout); // open if btn is pressed
    $("#btn2").click(strtBlackout); // open if btn is pressed
    $(".blackout").click(endBlackout); // close if click outside of popup
    $(".closeBox").click(endBlackout); // close if close btn clicked
});
```

```css
.blackout {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:301;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.msgbox {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    width:70%;
    height:60%;
    position:fixed;
    top:20%;
    left:15%;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:302;
    display:none;
}
.closeBox {
    background-color:#CC0000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:8px;
    float:right;
    border-radius:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div class="blackout"></div>
<div class="msgbox">
    <div class="closeBox">Close</div>
    Message Goes Here
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click Here" />
```

Comment: What is the question? Please try to reword to make it clearer

Comment: this works if i have one button but not if i have more then one with more then one pop up

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the `data` attribute for your input buttons. This way, you only have 1 blackout box, except the information it displays is dynamic.

My code explained -

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="openBlackout" value="Click Here" data-message="Some Message for Click Here Button" />
```

The `data-message` attribute of the button contains some message, also I gave it a class name, so that the function can run whenever an element with that class name is clicked. It does not necessarily have to be a button, you can do the same with an image.

```
$(document).on('click', '.openBlackout', function(){
  strtBlackout($(this).data('message'));
});
```

I then added a parameter to your `strtBlackout` function which will be the message that is displayed.

With the HTML now looking like below -

```
<div class="msgbox">
    <div class="closeBox">Close</div>
    <div class="message">Message Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

I changed added to your `strtBlackout` function in order to change that message.

```
function strtBlackout(message){
    $('.message').html(message);
    $(".msgbox").css("display", "block");
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
}
```

```js
//This is the function that closes the pop-up
function endBlackout(){
    $(".blackout").css("display", "none");
    $(".msgbox").css("display", "none");
}

//This is the function that closes the pop-up
function strtBlackout(message){
    $('.message').html(message);
    $(".msgbox").css("display", "block");
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
}

$(document).on('click', '.blackout, .closeBox', endBlackout);

$(document).on('click', '.openBlackout', function(){
  strtBlackout($(this).data('message'));
});

//Sets the buttons to trigger the blackout on clicks
/*    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(strtBlackout); // open if btn is pressed
    $("#btn2").click(strtBlackout); // open if btn is pressed
    $(".blackout").click(endBlackout); // close if click outside of popup
    $(".closeBox").click(endBlackout); // close if close btn clicked
});*/
```

```css
.blackout {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:301;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.msgbox {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    width:70%;
    height:60%;
    position:fixed;
    top:20%;
    left:15%;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:302;
    display:none;
}
.closeBox {
    background-color:#CC0000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:8px;
    float:right;
    border-radius:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div class="blackout"></div>
<div class="msgbox">
    <div class="closeBox">Close</div>
    <div class="message">Message Goes Here</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="openBlackout" value="Click Here" data-message="Some Message for Click Here Button" />
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="openBlackout" value="Click This" data-message="Some Message for Click This Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to create a new message box and new blackout element on each button click. So initially no blackout element or msgbox will exist.

```
var lastDialogZIndex = 0;

function createDialogWrapper(parent) {
    var dialogWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    $(dialogWrapper)
       .addClass('dialog-wrapper')
       .css('z-index', lastDialogZIndex)
       .appendTo(parent);

    return dialogWrapper;
}

function createBlackout(parent) {
    var blackout = document.createElement('div');
    $(blackout)
       .addClass('blackout')
       .css('z-index', lastDialogZIndex)
       .appendTo(parent);

    return blackout;
}

function createMsgBox(parent) {
    var msgBox = document.createElement('div');
    $(msgBox)
       .addClass('msgbox')
       .text('Message Goes Here')
       .css('z-index', lastDialogZIndex)
       .appendTo(parent);

    return msgBox;
}

function createCloseBox(parent) {
    var closeBox = document.createElement('div');
    $(closeBox)
       .addClass('closeBox')
       .text('Close')
       .css('z-index', lastDialogZIndex)
       .appendTo(parent);

    return closeBox;
}

function createDialogButton(parent) {
    var dialogButton = document.createElement('input');
    $(dialogButton)
       .addClass('openBlackout')
       .attr('value', 'Next dialog button')
       .attr('type', 'button')
       .css('z-index', lastDialogZIndex)
       .appendTo(parent);

    return dialogButton;
}

function buildDialog(parent) {
    var wrapper = createDialogWrapper(parent);
    var blackout = createBlackout($(wrapper));
    var msgBox = createMsgBox($(wrapper)); 
    var closeBox = createCloseBox($(msgBox));
    var nextDialogButton = createDialogButton($(wrapper));

    lastDialogZIndex = lastDialogZIndex + 1;
}

//dynamically create new dialog
function startBlackout() {
    var mainWrapper = $('#main-dialog-wrapper');
    buildDialog(mainWrapper);
}

// Remove the wrapper for the last dialog
function endBlackout() {
    $("#main-dialog-wrapper:last-child").remove();
    lastDialogZIndex = lastDialogZIndex - 1;
}
```

What's happening above is: you are creating the layout for the new dialog dynamically on each call for startBlackout().
Currently I use css attribute z-index in order to control which dialog is on top. (every other dialog shows on top of the other with higher z-index). If you have not used it, check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Since you can not click anywhere outside the dialog, the next button must be inside of it, so I currently create it dynamically with in startBlackout(), just for an example.

So, with this functionality, the html will look like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div id="main-dialog-wrapper"> </div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="openBlackout" value="Open dialog 1" />
```

And you use your other functionality just as before (onClick methods are the same).

But after all, I would propose that you use a library like that one http://jquerymodal.com/ , no need to reinvent the wheel every day. (:

Answer (score 0):

```
//add class
<div class="blackout"></div>
<div class="msgbox">
    <div class="closeBox">Close</div>
    Message Goes Here
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn" value="Click Here" />

//use class as selector
 $(".btn").click(strtBlackout);
```

check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/giantomakin/yg7ckfpd/1/